# Revert secondary y-scale in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
observed <- c("1000","2000","3000","4000")
simulated <- c("1100","2100","3100","4100")
error <- c("-1","-2","-0.5","-4")
Date <- c("2013-01-01","2013-01-02","2013-01-03","2013-01-04")
y <- data.frame(Date,observed,simulated,error)
y[-1] <- sapply(y[-1], as.character)
y[-1] <- sapply(y[-1], as.numeric)
y$Date <- as.Date(y$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

It compares observed with simulated daily river dicharges on the left y axis and shows the related difference in percent on the right y axis (note that the percentages are just an example here and are not correctly calculated).

I would like to plot all three in one graph with the percentage error plotted on the secondary y axis. I used the following code:

```
p<-ggplot(y, aes(x=Date))
p<-p + geom_line(aes(y=observed, colour = "observed"), size=1.5)
p<-p + geom_line(aes(y=simulated, colour = "simulated"), size=1.5)
p<-p + geom_line(aes(y=error*-500, colour="red"), size=1.5)

p<-p + scale_colour_manual(name="Discharge [m3/sec]", labels=c("observed","simulated","error"), values = c("blue", "black","red"))
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./-500,name = "Error [%]"))
p <- p + labs(y=expression(paste('Q [',m^3~s^-1,']'),
                       colour = "Parameter"))
p <- p + theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.87), legend.title=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

My problem is that the secondary y axis starts at -8 and goes down to 0 from top to bottom. What I would like to have is that the secondary y axis` zero is at the top and the -8 is at the bottom where the zero from the first y axis (left) is.

Comment: you want just change the labels or turn the secondary y scale upside down?

Comment: Yes, I would like to reverse the secondary y axis so that it goes from 0 to -8 top to bottom

Comment: try replacing `scale_y_continuous` with `scale_y_reverse`

Comment: oh nvm, that also switches the first y_scale, sorry

Comment: correct, I tried it and it reversed both y scales.

Comment: I haven't worked much with the secondary axis, but I believe it's meant to be a transformed version of the primary, so setting `trans = "reverse"` should work in the `sec_axis` call

Comment: another try: `scale_y_continuous("observed", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (maxv - .)/-500 , name = "Error [%]")` with `maxv <- max( as.integer(observed))`  just optical though, since it isn't possible with two not correct scaling y axis to plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your secondary axis looks like that is because that's how you transformed your data. Since you multiplied your `error` by `-500` in your 3rd `geom_line`, as the error gets smaller (ie, closer to `-8`), the line will go up. Therefore, for the secondary axis to correctly map to the data you have, it *must* be upside down (with `-8` at the top).

If you want `0` to be at the top, just divide your `error` and the `trans` formula in `sec_axis` by positive `500`:

```
ggplot(y, aes(x=Date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=observed, colour = "observed"), size=1.5) +
    geom_line(aes(y=simulated, colour = "simulated"), size=1.5) +
    geom_line(aes(y=error*500, colour = "error"), size=1.5) +
    scale_colour_manual(name="Discharge [m3/sec]",
                        values = c('observed' = "blue",
                                   'simulated' = "black",
                                   'error' = "red")) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./500, name = "Error [%]",
                                           breaks = c(0, -2, -4, -6, -8))) +
    labs(y=expression(paste('Q [',m^3~s^-1,']'),
                      colour = "Parameter")) +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.87),
          legend.title=element_blank(), 
          axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

And if you want to make the two plots overlap, you can manually add 8 to you `error` to move it up, and then subtract it from the `sec_axis` to keep the numbers correct:

```
ggplot(y, aes(x=Date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=observed, colour = "observed"), size=1.5) +
    geom_line(aes(y=simulated, colour = "simulated"), size=1.5) +
    geom_line(aes(y=(8 + error) * 500, colour = "error"), size=1.5) +
    scale_colour_manual(name="Discharge [m3/sec]",
                        values = c('observed' = "blue",
                                   'simulated' = "black",
                                   'error' = "red")) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(. / 500) - 8, name = "Error [%]",
                                           breaks = c(0, -2, -4, -6, -8))) +
    labs(y=expression(paste('Q [',m^3~s^-1,']'),
                      colour = "Parameter")) +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.87),
          legend.title=element_blank(), 
          axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

Additional tips:

1. You can link multiple `ggplot` functions with the `+` operator like I do above instead of saving the intermediate result to a variable each time like you do in your example
2. The correct way to use `scale_color_manual` is to pass a named vector to `values`. This ensures that the given color value (ie. `observed`) is always associated with the correct color (ie. `blue`).
3. If you want the error line to be smaller and less dominant, just reduce the transformation factor. If you multiply (in `geom_line`) and divide (in `sec_axis`) it by `100` instead of `500` you get a much flatter line. You'll have to play around with the number to get it to look like what you want. In `ggplot2`, the secondary axis must be a transformation of the primary axis, so you can't just pass in its own `limits=` argument.

Comment: @Tung Thanks! Good catch. I was building off OP's example and didn't even think to check the colors. I've fixed it.

Comment: @divibisan How can I make the error line on the y axis less obvious, e.g. extend the secondary y axis from 9 to -20 so that the red line is not as dominant but just an almost straight line?

Comment: @Matt The best way to minimize the significance of error line is to reduce the factor that you multiply the error by. If you multiply/divide it by `100` instead of `500` you get a much flatter line. You'll have to play around with that number a bit. In `ggplot`, the 2nd axis must be a transformation of the first axis, so you can't just give it a different `limits=` argument.